# OnApplyTemplate being called inifinitely when in a DataTemplate

Tags: windows-phone-7

I have a custom Windows Phone 7 control called 'TranscriptCell'. I have added a few DependencyPropetys to it, which works perfectly fine. I have added a breakpoint in the `void override OnApplyTemplate()` method, and when in my XAML file, I use the control like this:

```
<EUILib:TranscriptCell Title="Hello World" HostO="MSI India" />
```

the breakpoint is triggered exactly once, i.e. the method `void OnApplyTemplate()` is called exactly once.

However, when I do something like:

```
<ListBox x:Name="TranscriptList" ItemsSource="{Binding TranscriptItems}">
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <EUILib:TranscriptCell
                Title="{Binding ActTitle}"
                HostO="{Binding Host}"
            />
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

the breakpoint is being triggered endlessly. The binded source serves a list of EXACTLY 2 items when I'm testing, and it is confirmed that it is EXACTLY 2. Still, the `OnApplyTemplate()` method is being called endlessly. Why is this happening?

EDIT: After following from the breakpoint step-by-step, it seems that since there are 2 items that are initialized for each of the item in the list, `OnApplyTemplate()` is being called again and again for each of the instance. i.e., the methods are being called like, `instance1::OnApplyTemplate()`, then `instance2::OnApplyTemplate()`, then `instnace1::OnApplyTemplate()`... and so on and so forth endlessly.

Answer (score 2):

Remove the breakpoint and add required debug output via `System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine()`.
Coming out of the breakpoint is likely triggering the call to UpdateLayout. (I've seen this happen a bunch of times in other scenarios.)

As a quick test, does it still do this when you don't break into that method?

Comment: Yes it still does. It does so because I was actually constantly updating the DataContext of the ListBox due to a bug in my code. So, it's actually a bit of a misunderstanding. I'll give you an upvote for taking the time to answer my question, but I guess I can't mark it as an answer (not that you need any rep anyways :) ). Thanks a lot for taking the time to answer the question :)